# ¿como cifrar parámetros de la url en AngularJS (Angular 1)?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, querystring

estoy desarrollando un proyecto con angularjs, para hacer el cambio de contraseña, capturo el id del usuario loggeado y lo envío por la url, al otro lado en el controller de update, lo capturo con un `$stateParams` y lo asigno a una variable, y así traigo los

> datos del usuario con la función get y puedo actualizarlos;

funciona perfecto; el problema es que en la url se ve el valor del id de usuario, por ejemplo **localhost/#/user/update/1,** el lío es que no quiero que se vea el numero porque es inseguro, incluso si el usuario cambia el numero se ven los datos del user dueño de ese id, lo que busco es que aparezca algo mas o menos así **localhost/#/user/update/AQWDAWf15;** bueno he buscado y no he encontrado una manera de implementarlo con angular, ¿podrían ayudarme?.

este es el html donde envío el parámetro

```
<a class="boton_cerrar_sesion" id="transition" href="#/usuarios/update/{{vm.getCurrentIdUser()}}">Mi cuenta</a>
```

con el **geCurrentIdUSer()** capturo el id del user loggeado al dar click en el link (eso es una función aparte que no va al caso).

esto hace que al ir a la ruta del href se añada el id que capturé, así que sale esto en el navegador.

http://localhost:8001/usuarios/update/2 (este es el id del usuario loggeado).

al tomar esa ruta se carga el template del formulario de actualizar, y a su vez mediante directiva se carga el controlador

aqui capturo el id que viaja por la url

```
  var id = $stateParams.idUsuario;
  vm.usuarios = Usuarios.get({ idUsuario: id });
```

así asigno a  id el valor que viaja por la url, y traigo los datos del usuario que tiene ese id.

lo que necesito es que cifre al momento de enviar y que en la url el numero salga cifrado y no se vea.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo via POST, pero como tu lo quieres mantener en la url haz un factory , el codigo seria de esta forma

```
app.factory("userFactory", function() {
  return {
    userDetails: {id : 0 , 
          nombre : ""}
  };
});
```

en el controlador donde quieres almacenar los datos debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
app.controller("loginCtrl", function($scope, $state, userFactory) {
    userFactory.userDetails.id = 31;
     $state.go("cambio_clave_exitoso");
});
```

y en el controlador que recibes los multiples parametros de la siguiente forma:

```
 app.controller("detailsLoginSuccess", function($scope, $state, userFactory) {
    console.log(userFactory.userDetails , "mi detalle de usuario");
//si esta vacio el userDetails es por que le dieron refresh
});
```

puedo darte mas detalles que en el factory es como en Java seria un Pojo(Plain Old Java Object) seria un objeto plano solo podra ver el valor si previamente lo llenaro si le das f5 no lo veraz

Comment: Gracias pero eso ya lo tengo resuelto, me recibe el parametro y me actualiza, me guarda en la base de datos, tambien cabe menciona que con angular estoy consumiendo un API rest hecho en Java, y funciona perfecto, lo que quiero es que no se vea el numero de id en la url adjuntaré mi código, para que se aprecie mejor.

Comment: de esta forma no lo envias por la url de hecho queda oculto!, el usuario nunca vera en la url algo; es como si enviaras un formulario por post; puedes conseguir mas dudas como esta buscando como pasar variables de un controlador a otro en angular

Comment: buscaré entonces, :D pero el código que envías no se si se adapte a las demás cosas que tengo.

Comment: te comento mi caso debia pasar alrededor de 8 ids, obviamebte me preocupaba la seguridad como a ti; que hice, cree un factory con los valores vacios y luego lo envie; lo otro que puedes hacer es encriptar con un patron arbitrario que debe conocer tanto el frontend como el backend y luego desencriptarlo

Comment: ya te entiendo por lo pronto logre evitar que si cambia la url visualice algo, me explico solo deja ver sus datos, si cambia el numero manualmente de igual manera no lo dejará visualizar la información de otros usuarios.

Comment: hay otra forma con localstorage, guardas en el lado del cliente uno o varios valores, esto es comun en angular para guardar los tokens o el idioma por defecto del cliente

Comment: Gracias por el aporte leí que eso  contamina el rootscope,  por lo tanto  se usa mas cuando vas a enviar objetos complejos, no un numero (o es lo recomendado), sin embargo tome tu idea y lo que hice fue inyectar el id del user loggeado. usando la función que tengo en otro factory que me trae dicho valor, y lo inyecte directamente al controller desde ese factory así como me sugeriste, y no pasa por la url.                               var id =  $auth.getPayload().idUsuario;
        vm.usuarios = Usuarios.get({ idUsuario: id });   Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que tienes que hacer es cifrar el id en java y enviarlo crifrado en la respuesta.... el cliente lo tendra cifrado y cuando haga un request con esa cifra lo desifras en java y ya lo tienes decifrado. Al momento de que el cliente lo tenga cifrado la url va a estar cifrada porq eso fue lo que el servidor le escupió.

Comment: Intentaré de esta forma.